# Can someone explain to me how it appears that mysqli's class methods have their own sub-methods?

Tags: php, oop, methods, properties, extends

For example:

```
$m = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$q = $m->query('SELECT stuff FROM table');
while ($row = $q->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

How does the `query` method end up having its own distinct "sub-methods" like `fetch_assoc()`?

How can I replicate this behaviour using OOP?

**EDIT** ... would this be considered correct and / or good practice?

```
class MyClass {    
   function myMethod() {
      return new AnotherClass();
   }
}

class AnotherClass {
   function __construct() {
       $this->stuff = 'stuff';
   }
}
```

Then, I can do:

```
$obj = new MyClass;
$stuff_getter = $obj->myMethod();
echo $stuff_getter->stuff;
```

Comment: Because query returns a `mysqli_result` object - I suspect this is a case of "read the manual" : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: A method rarely returns itself, it returns data-structure like an object, string, array, etc. `$m` and `$q` in your case are objects and returned from respectively `mysqli::__construct()` and `mysqli::query()`

Comment: @RichardBernards: I thought constructor methods couldn't return values...?

Comment: _How can I replicate this behaviour using OOP?_ That is an object!!! Gota go with @CD001 on this. **Hit the books** [PHP: Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: Fair enough, I have been reading up on PHP OOP, I just need to wrap my head around it a little better.

Comment: Constructor methods return an instance of the class (object) you are instantiating, just like a normal instantiation would.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to archieve a specific situation or are you just exploring OO programming?

Comment: See answer, hope it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit opinion based what you are asking, but because i think a lot of people are strugling with this i will provide some general information about this case.
First of all, you can't say if this is a good practice or not. It depends on the intention and the context. See this code:

```
class MyClass {    
   function myMethod() {
      return new AnotherClass();
   }
}
```

Is it ok? Yes it's ok what you are doing, but note that you have a strong dependency here. If you ever want for some reason to have different implementations 
of `AnotherClass` you need to change the code.
You can prevent this by using dependency injection. Implement an interface in `AnotherClass` and inject it into `MyClass`. 
When you have another implementation of `AnotherClass` you can just pass it like the 'old' version. 
How to implement this is also depends on what the intention of your code is but i will provide a basic example of your code.

```
class MyClass {   

    private $aClass = null;

    function __construct($aClass)
   {
        $this->aClass = $aClass;
   }

   function myMethod() {
      return new $this->aClass();
   }
}

interface AnInterface
{

}

class AnotherClass implements AnInterface {
   function __construct() {
       $this->stuff = 'stuff';
   }
}


$obj = new MyClass(new AnotherClass());
$stuff_getter = $obj->myMethod();
echo $stuff_getter->stuff;
```

Now using this i can just create another implementation of `AnotherClass` and pass it to `MyClass` like i always did. Instead of your scenario where i need to add another function. E.g:

```
class AnotherClass2 implements AnInterface {
   function __construct() {
       $this->stuff = 'another stuff';
   }
}

$obj = new MyClass(new AnotherClass2());
$stuff_getter = $obj->myMethod();
echo $stuff_getter->stuff;
```

The second thing i notice is you aren't defining variables. I think it's a little opinion based, but i'm strongly against public variables (which in your case is by default). 
Create a variable and assign that variable in your constructor. Create getters and setters (if you are lazy you can create magic getters en setters ([see here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)). You would get something like this:

```
class AnotherClass implements AnInterface {

   private $stuff;

   function __construct() {
       $this->stuff = 'stuff';
   }

   public function getStuff()
   {
        return $this->stuff;
   }
}

$obj = new MyClass(new AnotherClass());
$stuff_getter = $obj->myMethod();
echo $stuff_getter->getStuff();
```

I hope this makes some clearness about your construction, although this might not be fully answering your question.

Two notes on this.

1. The interface is not always necessary in PHP, but it sure is the best practice.
2. Instead of implementing an interface you could also use an inheritance stucture if you have a lot of duplication and ofcourse you are allowed to use inheritance (is it an is-a relation?).

Your final code could be (as interface example) something like this:

```
class MyClass {   

    private $aClass = null;

    function __construct($aClass)
   {
        $this->aClass = $aClass;
   }

   function myMethod() {
      return new $this->aClass();
   }
}

interface AnInterface
{
    public function getStuff();
}

class AnotherClass implements AnInterface {

   private $stuff;

   function __construct() {
       $this->stuff = 'stuff';
   }

   public function getStuff()
   {
        return $this->stuff;
   }
}

class AnotherClass2 implements AnInterface {

   private $stuff;

   function __construct() {
       $this->stuff = 'another stuff';
   }

   public function getStuff()
   {
        return $this->stuff;
   }
}


$obj = new MyClass(new AnotherClass());
$stuff_getter = $obj->myMethod();
echo $stuff_getter->getStuff(); 

$obj = new MyClass(new AnotherClass2());
$stuff_getter = $obj->myMethod();
echo $stuff_getter->getStuff();
```